# Correct client denied by server configuration error after moving website to proxy

Tags: apache, proxy

My website directory structure was this:

```
/var/services/web/
```

A portion of my website is a Wordpress page called portal with a Ninja Forms plugin. Ninja forms stores uploaded files in a directory on the server for all to see. So to deal with that I did this in the site's configuration file:

```
<Directory "/var/services/web/portal/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/"> 
    AllowOverride None 
    Order deny,allow 
    Deny from all 
</Directory>
```

I have had to move my website to a proxy server and now the Ninja Forms directory structure is like this:

```
/var/services/web/MYWEBSITE/portal/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/
```

I am not sure how to make the above Apache config item work in the proxy server.  My proxy set up in httpd-ssl-vhost.conf-user is like this (port 80 is similar but I don't think that is an issue because I am only connecting ssl. Correct me if I am wrong):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.MYWEBSITE.com
DocumentRoot "/var/services/web/MYWEBSITE"
ErrorDocument 403 "/webdefault/error.html"
ErrorDocument 404 "/webdefault/error.html"
ErrorDocument 500 "/webdefault/error.html"
SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried just changing the path in the Apache config file to:

```
<Directory "/var/services/web/MYWEBSITE/portal/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/"> 
    AllowOverride None 
    Order deny,allow 
    Deny from all 
</Directory>
```

And this just produces the following error:

```
client denied by server configuration: /var/services/web/MYWEBSITE/portal/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms . . . etc.
```

So, I think I need to add lines to my proxy ssl set up. I could use tips on the proper SSL set up in my proxy server.  Other solutions I have found here appear to be changing the Deny from All line and I do not want that.

Comment: You have `Deny from all` in your `Directory` section. It will deny everybody unless you allow access somewhere else in the config, what you will need to show for anyone to help. If not, I guess you meant `Allow from all` ?